# Save input form on custom field

Tags: custom-field, metabox, customization

I have an idea but I don't know if it's working on wordpress.

I wanna save/stock input values on a custom field or metabox, is that something can work on wordpress? I couldn't find any way to develop such a thing.

I hope I had describe my idea.

Comment: So, you're saying you want to create some default custom fields with default values on post creation?

Comment: @socki03 exactly, I have created a custom post type with many custom fields, so i want to save what people insert in the form input on the custom field.

Comment: Then you'll want to use the save_post action once your post is created, you can update_post_meta all the form fields to custom fields.  Unfortunately, I can't be more specific without any more information.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post